# Loud clicking noise

Tags: noise, jeep

It's a 2005 Jeep Liberty limited. Roughly 140000 miles. No major overhauls or problems previously. However today when I started the car there was a loud clicking or tapping noise when accelerating and idling. The frequency increases with rpms and gets a little louder. You can also 'feel' the clock in the gas pedal when it clicks. The check engine light is blinking. But I don't know why. Assuming it has to do with this but it will be a while before we can put it in the shop. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

A flashing check engine light is letting you know that you have a sever misfire. Don't drive the car with a misfire because that may damage the catalytic converter. Have the car towed to your local mechanic.

Comment: Neighbors gonna pull the error code will update once I know what it is

Comment: Doesn't a modern ECU disable fuel injection to the cylinder with severe misfire, thus preventing cat damage? A 2005 car will probably also have coil-on-plug design, making it unlikely that all cylinders are severely misfiring at the same point of time.

Comment: @juhist Theoretically, yes. Practically it's a crapshoot as to whether the system kicks in and when. Some cars have a very high threshold of when to shut the injector off. Others do it even if the car sneezes.